# Class with vector of objects of other class

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class Student:

```
class Student {
private:
    unsigned int id;
    string name;
    vector<unsigned int> grades;
public:
    Student(unsigned int id, string name, vector<unsigned int> grades);

    void setid(unsigned int id) { this->id = id; }
    unsigned int getid() { return this->id; }
    void setname(string name) { this->name = name; }
    string getname() { return this->name; }
    void setgrades(vector<unsigned int> grades) { this->grades = grades; }
    vector<unsigned int> getgrades() { return this->grades; }

    unsigned int getcoefgrades()
    {
        unsigned int coef = this->grades[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < this->grades.size(); i++) {
            coef *= this->grades[i];
        }
        return coef;
    }

    int getcoefname() { return this->name.length() % 2; }
};
Student :: Student(unsigned int id, string name, vector<unsigned int> grades)
{
    this->id = id;
    this->name = name;
    this->grades = grades;
}
```

And I have some objects of this class (here is all main function):

```
int main()
{
    Student Ivanov(324, "Ivanov", { 3, 4, 5 });
    Student Petrov(532, "Petrov", { 5, 4, 2 });
    Student Sidorov(234, "Sidorov", { 3, 5, 2 });

    cout << Petrov.getcoefname();

    system("pause");
}
```

My target is to create a class Group. The object of such a class must store student's data as a vector of objects of the class Student.
Have you any ideas how to create this?

Comment: What did you try and what did fail? Please put some effort in solving the task before asking.

Comment: `std::vector<Student> students;`

Comment: @JesperJuhl short, sweet, correct.

Comment: He's probably having trouble with creating a vector of `Student`, which doesn't have a default constructor...

Comment: A better StackOverflow question would have shown the code that tries to accomplish the task and the error(exact text of the error message) resulting when the try failed. When you don't show your attempt here you don't usually get the help you wanted. There are some guidelines here on that topic: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2):

To create a vector of `Student`s all you need is

```
std::vector<Student> students;
```